# Allow Only Specific Words for Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, attributes

How do you restrict strings allowed in a string field to specific words?

Example: I have a model attribute `animal:string` that I would like to exclusively accept `["dog", "cat", "bird", "fish"]`. Every thing else would make the object invalid.

Comment: You can use Rails [Enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) otherway. This [blog post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/whats-new-in-edge-rails-active-record-enum) also related to what I said you to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an [inclusion](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion) validation to your model:

```
validates :animal, inclusion: { in: %w(dog cat bird fish) }
```

Comment: They are two totally different things.  ActiveRecord enum allows you to map values to integers to store in the db, whereas the validation ensures that only one of a set of values is valid.

Answer (score 2):

As I said, I'd go with Rails [Enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) feature.

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum animals: %w(dog cat)
  # ...
end
```

[There is one gotcha](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/whats-new-in-edge-rails-active-record-enum) which you might notice since this is called enum: *you will need to update your database column to be an integer value*. Rails will do implicit mapping between the integer value and the index of the value in the array automatically

If you go with `Enum` feature, having the single line of code, Rails will generate several helper methods for you:

```
# Query method
model_name.dog?
model_name.cat?
#..

# Action method
model_name.cat!
model_name.dog!
#..

# List of statuses and their corresponding values in the database.
model_name.animals
```

**Tried and Tested :**

```
[arup@app]$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.1)
[1] pry(main)> Pet.create!(animals: 'cat')
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "pets" ("animals", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["animals", 1], ["created_at", "2015-02-19 18:27:28.074640"], ["updated_at", "2015-02-19 18:27:28.074640"]]
   (42.2ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Pet id: 5, animals: 1, created_at: "2015-02-19 18:27:28", updated_at: "2015-02-19 18:27:28">
[2] pry(main)> Pet.create!(animals: 'cow')
ArgumentError: 'cow' is not a valid animals
from /home/arup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@app/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/enum.rb:103:in 'block (3 levels) in enum'
[3] pry(main)> Pet.animals
=> {"dog"=>0, "cat"=>1}
[5] pry(main)> Pet.first.dog?
  Pet Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "pets".* FROM "pets"   ORDER BY "pets"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> false
[6] pry(main)> Pet.first.cat?
  Pet Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "pets".* FROM "pets"   ORDER BY "pets"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> true
[7] pry(main)> Pet.first.cow?
  Pet Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "pets".* FROM "pets"   ORDER BY "pets"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method 'cow?' for #<Pet:0xbf8455c>
from /home/arup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@app/gems/activemodel-4.1.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'
[8] pry(main)>
```

`Pet.create!(animals: 'cow')` throws error, which confirmed that, `Pet` model wouldn't accept anything other than the *enum* values.

Comment: @softcode No issue... Cheers!! :-) It's always fun to know several ways.

Answer (score 0):

you can use select field in your form, and write this in your model:

```
module Animal
    dog = 1
    cat = 2
    bird = 3
    fish = 4
end
```

and in tour form:

```
<%= f.select  :animal, { "dog" => 1, "cat" => 2, "bird" => 3, "fish" => 4} %>
```